# In-text citations - First and subsequent citations - AMA

Tags: publications, citations, journals, paper-submission, citation-style

Am new to writing research article. While I am following the guidelines [here](https://libguides.jcu.edu.au/ama/in-text-citations)

Am I right to understand that whenever we refer to a source, we cite them in-text.

Let's say my paragraph has 100 lines.

I refer the source for the first time in L10. So, I write xxxx[superscript 1]

I refer the source again in L25... Should I again use the [superscript 1] here?

Basically, should we use in-text citation whenever I refer/mention about the source?

Or just in-text citation for just the 1st mention is enough (and we don't have to in-text cite the subsequent mentions)?

Comment: Bad writing style. A paragraph cannot have 100 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use again the same superscript as before.

Here is a random example from *JAMA Network Open* ([this paper](http://doi.org/10.1001/jamanetworkopen.2020.9278) at p. 5). Note the repeated use of <sup>1</sup> or <sup>24</sup>:

[image: superscripts]

Comment: Thanks, upvoted and accepted